# Is there a graphical interface for Windows to run Tor Browser using specific list of ExitNodes rather than editing torrc every time?

Tags: configuration, windows, exit-relays, firefox, location

I wonder if there is a graphical interface for **Windows** to run **Tor Browser** using specific list of **ExitNodes** rather than editing **torrc** every time?

There are too many steps to perform this. Too bad that Tor Browser itself does not support that. It would be a very nice feature to be able to click a couple of times rather than finding country codes, editing configuration files and only then running Tor Browser. It would be even cooler if that program could start up the **firefox.exe** itself aswell. Sounds alot simply however.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. After doing some search I didn't find such application, so I wrote my own. **Tor Browser Launcher** is written in Delphi using FireMonkey framework and compiled for 32/64-bit Windows architectures:

[Tor Browser Launcher](https://www.te-home.net/?do=work&id=tbl)

[image: Screenshot]

Any further feature requests are welcome. The interface will be updated after your needs of configuration set.

Regards.